Protection against inrush current on battery charger
I'm designing a PCB for a battery powered robot. This battery must manage both the charge of and discharge of a 8S (29 V nominal) Li-ion battery. The voltages of the application cause big inrush peaks when connecting either the charge terminal or the battery. I have successfully tested a crude inrush limiter like the one in the image for the charge terminal.

My problem is that while this work for the charging voltage it will not work for the battery, because in this case the current must be able to flow in the opposite direction for charging (I don't need inrush current in that direction, only to allow current to flow, I only need inrush current when plugging a battery). Just relaying on the P-MOSFET body diode is not an option because of the power losses.
My idea is to use a ideal diode (a MOSFET and a IC like LM74670QDGKRQ1) in this direction, but I feel like I'm overlooking a better solution and searching online I haven't found anything relevant to my problem.
Am I going in the right direction? Does anyone have experience with this problem? Is there a better solution?

It turns out my question didn't make sense because I was misunderstanding how a P-MOSFET works. As long as Vgs is large enough the mosfet will conduct, no matter the current direction. The reverse current would flow trought the body diode only if the MOSFET was closed, which is not the case in my situation.
So there was no problem to solve: power dissipation is the same in both directions, and it is the power dissipated on Rds.
